# HipChat API Tokens v1 vs. v2

Tags: hipchat

In v1 of the HipChat API, you could create a token (let's call it "Notifier") that would be able to notify any room on the server.  Any messages sent using this token will appear from "Notifier" in HipChat.

In v2, you can create a personal access token with notification permissions that can post on your behalf, but they will show up under your name, not "Notifier."  Alternatively, you can create a room-specific token with notification permissions, but you have to create a separate token for each room you want to notify.

Is there a way to mimic the above-described v1 behavior in v2?

Answer (score 0):

No way to mimic the v1 behavior. The limitation on the v2 is by design. What are you trying to accomplish?